# Get Klockwork count from command line

Tags: build, klocwork, rogue-wave

We are trying to get Klockwork count from command line, which is showed in UI in klockwork dashboard.We tried curl it is not working.

We need to fail the build pipeline if Klockwork count is increased from Baseline count.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the "search" action to fetch the data you need through webapi (curl).
Still, you can consider using Klocwork plugin in Jenkins to achieve your goal effectively.